# Spring Web MVC tiles attribute error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tiles, apache-tiles

I am using tiles in spring web mvc, where I am getting the error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="base.definition" template="/template/mainTemplate.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Piranha"></put-attribute>
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/template/header.jsp"></put-attribute>
        <put-attribute name="content" value=""></put-attribute>
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/template/footer.jsp"></put-attribute>
    </definition>


    <definition name="adminHome" extends="base.definition">
        <put-attribute name="content" value="/view/manage/adminHome.jsp"></put-attribute>
        <put-attribute name="maincontent" value=""></put-attribute>
    </definition>
    <definition name="insertProduct" extends="adminHome">
        <put-attribute name="maincontent" value="/view/manage/insertProduct.jsp"></put-attribute>
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

AdminHome.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="tiles" uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" %>

<div align="center">Restricted Area - Administrator</div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            DATA    
        </td>
        <td>
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="maincontent" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Error

```
org.apache.tiles.template.NoSuchAttributeException: Attribute 'maincontent' not found.
    org.apache.tiles.template.DefaultAttributeResolver.computeAttribute(DefaultAttributeResolver.java:50)
    org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.resolveAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:165)
    org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.execute(InsertAttributeModel.java:121)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:299)
    org.apache.jsp.view.manage.adminHome_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f0(adminHome_jsp.java:116)
    org.apache.jsp.view.manage.adminHome_jsp._jspService(adminHome_jsp.java:87)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:684)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:678)
    org.apache.tiles.request.jsp.JspRequest.doInclude(JspRequest.java:123)
    org.apache.tiles.request.AbstractViewRequest.dispatch(AbstractViewRequest.java:47)
    org.apache.tiles.request.render.DispatchRenderer.render(DispatchRenderer.java:47)
    org.apache.tiles.request.render.ChainedDelegateRenderer.render(ChainedDelegateRenderer.java:68)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:259)
    org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:188)
    org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.execute(InsertAttributeModel.java:132)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:299)
    org.apache.jsp.template.mainTemplate_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f2(mainTemplate_jsp.java:340)
    org.apache.jsp.template.mainTemplate_jsp._jspService(mainTemplate_jsp.java:130)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest.forward(ServletRequest.java:265)
    org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest.doForward(ServletRequest.java:228)
    org.apache.tiles.request.AbstractClientRequest.dispatch(AbstractClientRequest.java:57)
    org.apache.tiles.request.render.DispatchRenderer.render(DispatchRenderer.java:47)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:259)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:397)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:238)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:221)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.DefinitionRenderer.render(DefinitionRenderer.java:59)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:96)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
```

Comment: I don't think "maincontent" attribute is available in spring tiles 3.0

Comment: I don't think you can insert that `maincontent` attribute in `AdminHome.jsp`, you should be inserting it in `mainTemplate.jsp`. I think you are getting that error because `adminhome.jsp` is not a template. I have an demo project on Spring-Tiles on [Github](https://github.com/RawSanj/spring-tiles-sample-app) that might help you.

Comment: @SanjayRawat, adminHome.jsp is not the main template. It is present inside another template. Now I want to put another template inside it. Is it not possible?

Answer (score 1):

There are few problem with your configuration

First of all adminHome is extending the main definition.
When you extend a definition you must have only attributes of the parent definition. You can only override attributes not add new ones.

So you need to add maincontent to the base definition and adjust the mainTemplate.jsp accordingly

Something like below

```
<definition name="base.definition" template="/template/mainTemplate.jsp">
   <put-attribute name="title" value="Piranha"></put-attribute>
   <put-attribute name="header" value="/template/header.jsp"></put-attribute>
   <put-attribute name="content" value=""></put-attribute>
   <put-attribute name="maincontent" value=""></put-attribute>
   <put-attribute name="footer" value="/template/footer.jsp"></put-attribute>
</definition>

<definition name="adminHome" extends="base.definition">
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/view/manage/adminHome.jsp"></put-attribute>
    <put-attribute name="maincontent" value="/page/of/your/content"></put-attribute>
</definition>
```

However, I do not understand why you want to have two pages of content for a single definition.....

It is also important to add maincontent in your template with tiles:insertAttribute
AdminHome.jsp should not have tiles attributes but only the content of your page.

Please refer to the official [documentation](https://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/basic/concepts.html) for further help